# my if statement in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have range input using HTML and using javascript to show the value. i want if input value is more than 3 than `id='c0'` is show and `id='c1'` is hidden and if input value less than 3 than `id='c0'` is hidden and `id='c1'` is show. what i get now is when change whatever value it will show `id='c1'` and hide `id='c0'`

```
<style> #c1{ display: none; }</style>
<input onchange="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none'" class="range-slider__range slider InputC" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="50" name="anak_laki">
<span class="range-slider__value">0</span>

<ul id="c0" class="data-list-2 clearfix">
                        <li>
                        Ini muncul kalo kurang dari 0
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="c1" class="data-list-2 clearfix">
                        <li>
                        Ini akan muncul kalo lebi dari 0
                        </li>
                    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
//This is code for range value
var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');

  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
//This is code for range value end

//Form Jumlah Harta
function startCalc(){
interval = setInterval("calc()",1);}
function stopCalc(){
clearInterval(interval);}
//InputC
$(".InputC").click(function(){
  if($(this).val() > 3){
    $("#c0").show();
    $("#c1").hide();
  }else{
    $("#c0").hide();
    $("#c1").show();
  }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: `if (Number($(this).val()) > 3){...` All values stored in a form control are strings not numbers therefore before any computation or comparison convert the string into a number.

Comment: still not working bro

Comment: what's this `rangeSlider();` brah? It didn't get called before , bru?

Comment: @zer00ne it's plugin http://rangeslider.js.org/

Comment: That's not how it's used and you've made a function expression with the same name, then invoked again.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems very overcomplicated for what you are trying to do.
This is how I would do this:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#range").on("change", function(){toggle($(this).val())});
  toggle($("#range").val());
});

function toggle(val) {
  if (val >= 1 && val < 3) {
    $("#c1").show();
    $("#c0, #c2").hide();
  } else if(val < 1) {
    $("#c0").show();
    $("#c1, #c2").hide();
  } else {
    $("#c2").show();
    $("#c0, #c1").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="2" />

<p id="c0">range < 1</p>
<p id="c1">range < 3</p>
<p id="c2">range >= 3</p>
```

Comment: but if i want another statement like if it 0, it will not work. example if if (val < 1) {

Answer (score -1):

Use `parseInt` .

```
if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 3){<br/>
$("#c0").show();<br/>
    $("#c1").hide();<br/>
  }else{<br/>
    $("#c0").hide();<br/>
    $("#c1").show();<br/>
  }<br/>
<br/>
```

this may work.

Comment: Thanks for providing a possible answer! Remember to use the code tool to format your code to make it easy to read and understand. You should also include an explanation of your answer if possible.